# How can I get Gradle module name programmatically

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to obtain Gradle's module name programmatically in Java code?

I need it to access module's build files under the `MODULE_NAME/build/intermediates` directory, but hardcoding module name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get the current's module name you can just access Gradle's `project` object

```
project.name
```

Will return, for the module `app`

> app

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Answer (score 2):

You can access `project` variable inside your build script that is instance of [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html). It has various getters like `projectDir` or `buildDir` and since this is quite common to use them it is documented in [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html).

Alternatively you can find this path if you look for an output of a task that generates files there.

If you need to know this location in your test you can pass it from build script using system property like this:

`test {
    systemProperty "buildFolder", project.buildDir.absolutePath
}`

BTW: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/gradle/idea.gradle#L192 has a trick how to update run configurations in IntelliJ's workspace with properties that you need for test execution. This can be useful if you run JUnit test inside IJ (without delegating to Gradle).

Comment: And how I'd use it in Java code? I need it in unit test runner, so having it in build.gradle doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You should have said what you needed it for!
Try passing it to your test case as a system property from the Gradle build script like Radim suggested. Then your test code can access it using System.getProperty("buildFolder").

Comment: This always points to the root module in a multi module / monorepo project